# How to make Eclipse CDT permanently use C++11 build settings for imported C++ projects and wizard-created projects?

Tags: c++11, eclipse-cdt

For every project I have to keep right-clicking the project to change the flag in the C++ Build properties ([see here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features)). Is there a way I can set this to be the default?